# Automatic Day Assign

Tags: c#, datetime

I need help about assigning day automatically. I couldn't find correct way.
Now problem is that I have fitness program. And I will add new user. When I add I will add program too. Fitness program has limit.

For example. 8 seans. Then user chooses every Saturday and Sunday.

`16.03.2019`, `17.03.2019`, `23.03.2019`, `24.03.2019`,
`30.03.2019`, `31.03.2019`, `06.04.2019`, `07.04.2019`

The dates will be assign automatically due to his chosen. uye.DAYS choosed days of week. For example '0,6' and uye.SURE means limit of seans

```
if(uy.UYELIK== "PLATES")
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
   
    for (int i = 0; i < uye.SURE; i++)
    {
        date = date.Add(duration);
        var list = uye.DAYS.Split(',');
        for(int j = 0; j < list.Length; j++)
        {
          if ((int)date.DayOfWeek == Convert.ToInt32(list[j]))
          {
              HR_FITNESS_USER_PLATES_PROGRAM program = new HR_FITNESS_USER_PLATES_PROGRAM();
              program.REF_HOCA = uye.HOCA;program.SEANS_LIMIT = uye.SURE;program.SEANS_TIME = date;program.REF_UYELIK = uy.ID;program.SICIL = uye.SICIL.ToString();
              db.HR_FITNESS_USER_PLATES_PROGRAM.Add(program);db.SaveChanges();  
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not correct. Here I can't increase day if not one of them. How can I do it?

Comment: Please don't post code with huge chunks of leading whitespace. It just makes it harder to read. You can hold down the `Alt` key in VS to select an arbitrary rectangle of text so you don't need to copy the whitespace in the first place but, even if you do copy it, you can still use the code button in the editor to remove excess. Do what you can to help us help you.

Comment: I understand turkish, but i can't understand what you want to do. I think the best way is traditional way, which user selects days and times with calendar.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to insert a weekend fitness program for a member. Here is a simple psuedocode for that,

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today; //today

int currentDayOfWeek = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek; //today

//saturday of this week, disregarding if today is 
//saturday or sunday, it is up to you to enhance this.
DateTime thisSaturday = startDate.AddDays(6 - currentDayOfWeek); 

var sessions = 8;

for (int i = 0; i<sessions; i++)
{
    SaveToDb(thisSaturday);
    thisSaturday = thisSaturday.AddDays(7);  //next week's weekend       
}

private void SaveToDb(DateTime saturday)
{
    DateTime sunday = saturday.AddDays(1);
    //insert data for saturday and sunday
}
```